# ESP32 and the Microsoft Azure Device Provisioning Service

Tags: esp32

I am currently experimenting the the ESP32. In general connecting to WLAN and also to the Microsoft Azure IoT Hub works fine. But unfortunately i coulnt find any information on using the ESP32 with the Microsoft Azure Device Provisioning Service. That means connecting and registering an ESP32 to the Microsoft Azure IoT Hub with a certificate.

Has anyone did this before? Maybe some guiding links etc.?

Comment: a Google search returns what appear to be valid examples ... what search terms did you use?

Comment: "esp32 azure device provisioning service" was my search

Comment: that's close to what i searched and found this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/esp32-iot-devkit-get-started/sample/

Comment: Thank you, but i know this page and this is only about "Starting with ESP32 and the IoT Hub" in VS Code. Thats not what i am looking for. Sorry.

Comment: You can open an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino to ask I guess, if that's the ilbrary you're using for connecting. Microsoft people should know their products best.